# Как раздвигать на изображении два края подвески на основе ширины кулона?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать такой же функционал?
Чтобы подвеска удлинялась или укорачивалась в зависимости от количества символов, введенных в строку?
И как можно менять шрифты, в зависимости от выбранного дизайна?
Возможно есть готовые решения? Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первым решением в голову приходит такое:

1. У нас есть 3 блока абсолютно спозиционированных. 
   Блок с текстом и 2 блока цепочки.
2. Первый блок выравниваем в центру блока при изменения текста вычисляя ширину блока с текстом и родительского блока.
3. В ручную задаём верхние точки цепочки.
4. Определяем верхние точки текста.
5. Делаем блок с началом в верхней точке цепочки и длинной равной расстоянию между верхними точками цепочки и верхними точками текста. И поворачиваем блок css свойством rotate на угол, который вычисляем так же по 2 точкам(верхними точками цепочки и верхними точками текста).
6. На фон у созданных блоков кладём повторяющееся изображение цепочки

Требуется поддержка rotate.

Если есть вопросы готов подробнее расписать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Текстовый блок должен иметь width:auto;position:absolute;top:200px(к примеру). Через JS определяем ширину блока и ширину рабочей области. Тогда left блока с текстом будет `(ширина области - ширина блок)/2`. Тем самым мы находим координаты точки B (top:200;left:только что выяснили).
3. Координаты точки A у нас должны быть жёстко заданы в JS.
4. Как получить координаты точек B и D описал во 2 пункте
5. Получаем координаты точки A1 из координат точек A и B — думаю по рисунку будет понятно. Получили треугольник по нему мы можем узнать длинну стороны AB — это будет ширина нашего нового блока. 
   Начало блока будет в точке A. Ну и по треугольнику AA1B мы сможем найти угол на который нужно повернуть.

Вторую сторону цепочки делаем примерно так же

Comment: Круто!
1. <div id="main" style="position: relative;">
<div calss="text" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div calss="podves1" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div calss="podves2"  style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
2. А как сделать при изменении текста вычислять ширину блока с текстом и родительского блока?
3. Это скорее всего top, left нужно указать?
4. Тут также top, left?
5. Вот это не совсем понял.
6. С фоном круто придумано)

Comment: Сейчас к ответу приложу изображение

Comment: @bakusite добавил изображение с описанием

Comment: @bakusite всё понятно?